# Try to insert loop into __init__

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, loops, class

I have a object `Quiz` in Django database, which contain `test_name` and `num_of_questions` columns. I'm trying to get that values all render name, count questions and render columns for the questions in a next step(with appropriate quiz name). I'm new in classes, so I would like to ask, if I'm doing it right?

```py
from .models import Quiz 

class rendered():
    quizs = Quiz.objects.all()
    for quiz in quizs:
        quizname = quiz.test_name
        n_o_q = quiz.num_of_questions
        tup = (quizname, n_o_q)


    def __init__(self, quiz_sum):
        self.quiz_sum = tup
        super(rendered, self).__init__()
```

Comment: You're overwriting `tup` each time through the loop. So when the `__init__` method runs, it just contains the information from the last quiz. You should probably put the information in a list.

Comment: @Barmar should it be a list of tuples?

Comment: That seems reasonable. It all depends on how you plan on using it.

Comment: List comprehensions can decrease readability for complex operations, but for this, it's easy to write a simple, readable one: `((q.test_name, q.num_of_questions) for q in Quiz.objects.all())` Note that this returns a generator; depending on how and where you want to use the result, either using a list (`[...]` instead of `(...)`) or explicitly coercing to a tuple (`tuple(...)` instead of `(...)` to force evaluation might be a good idea.